# DataGridView System.FormatException c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a datagrid which populated from List(TradeReport) datasource. There is a column named "TransactTime" that has Int64 datatype. But, I want to convert every cell in that column into a String type. I converted the datatype first before set the value into it. But, still got an error:

The following exception occured in the DataGridView: System.Exception: 7/04/2017 8:30:59 AM is not a valid value for Int64. What's wrong?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

List<TradeReport> tradeList = client.getTradeReports(criteria);
tradeGridView.DataSource = tradeList;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{
    double time = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TransactTime"].Value);
    string dts = dt.AddSeconds(time).ToLocalTime().ToString();

    row.Cells["TransactTime"].ValueType = typeof(String);
    row.Cells["TransactTime"].Value = dts;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the error is obvious... your trying to put a string into an int value;

Comment: @JohnG I already convert the datatype of each cell into a string. Why it still doesn't accept string?

Comment: @JohnG have you seen my code? Yes it is an int, but I convert it to string later before insert into it.

Comment: Couldn't you just add another property to your TradeReport class of type string, populate it however you like, and hide the long column?

Comment: @Kris I'm not allowed to change anything in the class, because it is company standard.

Comment: You could create a 'presentation' model similar to TradeReport(which i assume is a POCO class or DTO) and map/convert the properties over.

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: I ran the posted code and it worked as you describe without errors… Again, what line is throwing this error?

Comment: You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... moving on. Good Luck.

Comment: @JohnG how can you ran the code without getting the original List<TradeReport>

Comment: Well since you did not supply it... i created my own int column and converted to string using your code. Again...You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you considered, simply making a ‘DataTable’ of the final structure you desire, then loop through the list of your class, convert the desired items  and place the converted items into the `DataTable` then set the grid’s data source to this table.

Comment: @JohnG please answer below with example code. And I will vote if it success.

Comment: What is there to answer? Your code appears to work; at least my test of YOUR code was successful. I have asked twice what lines throw this error?. I am not fond of playing twenty questions to determine what you are not able to articulate. I am sure you will find a solution. Good Luck.

Comment: The answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781007/define-datagridview-column-type-programmatically answered why I can't change the datatype once the datagrid has created.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a class called 'ExtendedTradeReport' which inherits from TradeReport:

```
public class ExtendedTradeReport : TradeReport
{
    public string TransactTimeString { get; set; }
}
```

2.Map your properties into the new class.

3.Perform your type conversions.

4.Use as the DataSource for your GridView

5.Hide the TransactTime column.

Comment: This solution may work. Thanks for that. But, I don't know if we can do something with datagridviewcolumn property, but in fact it didn't work.